# Live processing getUserMedia audio using the ScriptProcessorNode

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, web-audio-api, getusermedia

I'm trying to get some live data on microphone data. So I hooked up a ScriptProcessorNode to the output of my live audio as follows (coffeescript):

```
audioSource = navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true},(stream)->
    source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream)

    analyser = context.createScriptProcessor(1024,1,1)
    source.connect(analyser)

    analyser.onaudioprocess = (e)->
        \\Processing Takes Place here
```

However the onaudioprocess functions is never being called. What do I need to do to make it run?

Comment: You don't say if you're getting the getUserMedia callback, if audio input works elsewhere.. do you have a live example somewhere to debug?

Comment: If I add `source.connect(context.destination)` I can hear my audio loop back, so the input is working.

Comment: You really should post a reduced test case to JSFiddle. I suspect there's more going on. The fact that you're assigning the return value (which is undefined, by the way) of `getUserMedia` to a variable seems like a red flag to me. There's really not much help anyone can offer without a full example of your code.

Comment: getUserMedia takes an error function after the success function, you should add one in there. You need to be serving the page (not just from local) for getUserMedia to work.

Answer (score 2):

`ScriptProcesser`'s `onaudioprocess` event will not start if its output is not connected to some other node.

You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/nTWtt/) to see it in action.

```
var scr = context.createScriptProcessor(1024,1,1);

// uncomment the line below and onaudioprocess will start
//scr.connect(context.destination);

scr.onaudioprocess = function(){
    console.log('test');
};
```

Simply connect the output of your `ScriptProcessor` to `context.destination` or a dummy `gain` node and `onaudioprocess` will start.

Comment: This is actually a webkit bug (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92768). You don't need to connect the destination in firefox (and in fact, it will cause problems if you do).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.  I think it will work for you.

```
var source = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        var proc = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 2, 2);
        source.connect(proc);
        proc.connect(context.destination);
        proc.onaudioprocess = function(event)
        {
            var audio_data = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)|| new Float32Array(2048);
            console.log(audio_data);
            iosocket.emit('audiomsg',audio_data); 
        }
```